# Saving a browser url with Ruby and watir-webdriver

Tags: ruby, url, save, watir-webdriver

I'm using watir-webdriver to do my GUI smoke tests, and one area I'd like to test out is redirecting from a dynamic url

Is it possible to *save* the url to a file, then load it for use?

What I'm thinking of in **pseudo code**:

```
@browser.goto 'google.com'
@browser.url.save
```

in another test

```
@browser.load url
continue testing....
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Also, `watir-webdriver` gem has been deprecated in favor of the `watir` gem. Update to to Watir 6 to get access to all of the new features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write a string to a file you can just do that:

```
 File.open('path/to/yourfile', 'w') { |file| file.write(@browser.url) }
```

You can use it in the other test like this:

```
File.open('path/to/yourfile', "rb") { |file| @browser.goto(file.read) }
```

Comment: Oh wow, I pretty much facepalmed as soon as I read your answer.  Yup, this definitely works!